# Windows Invalidated after GParted partition?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7, gparted

I installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my computer on a tiny 20 GB Partition. I decided this was far too small, so I used GParted, resized the partition to an 80 GB partition, and Reinstalled the GRUB bootloader. However, the next time I booted back into Windows, I was told "You may be a victim of software counterfeiting." I tried activating using my Windows 7 product key (Which I couldn't get from teh installation disk, because the computer was given to me by a friend, I used WinKeyFinder 2) but it's telling me "Your computer is not yet activated with genuine windows key." I know this is bullcrap because my computer was working properly just a few weeks ago! I talked to Microsoft support but they were no help. No, I'm at my wits end trying to validate this freaking product key because I want to install 64 Bit windows on my computer, but I have no Valid product key! Someone help me before I go insane!

Comment: How do you know your friend had a "genuine" windows installed?

Comment: True, you're right. But I don't know if he did have genuine windows installed, but I think it is most likely he did. Do you know if it's possible to re-validate my product key? I used an "Online PID checker" and that says it's valid.

Comment: I'm not at all sure about Windows, you could try @ superuser.com , or a web search? I just know I'm happy never being bothered about "genuine ms" software again. Ubuntu/Mint/any linux can be great (as long as it runs the hardware)...

Answer (score 0):

Changing the partition size does not automatically change the filesystem size, so try just putting the partitions back to the way they were, and see if Windows not works.  If so, resize next time from within Windows, then run chkdisk a few times before doing anything else.  Did you look on the bottom of the machine for a label with a product key (if you still need it).
After increasing the Ubuntu partition, look into resize2fs to resize the filesystem

```
man resize2fs
```

for the info on running it.